# Industrial programmable radio transceiver

Tags: networking, wifi, wireless

*(I hope this kind of questions are tolerated here. Otherwise, please say it in the comment and I will delete the question)*

I have to create a wireless network of over 200 devices, placed in the same area.
WiFi is not suitable here due to the limitation of the numbers of devices handled by the routers.

Some time ago I've already done something similar using the CC110L transceiver by Texas Instruments. I mean, I set up a radio network and then I built a single "gateway" between the radio network and the WiFi one.

The problem is the current customer doesn't like custom PCBs... he requires an industrial product (ready-to-use commercial product). I'm not able to find such a product with the following features:

- programmable transceiver (MCU on board for user applications) based on CC110L or similar (SRD/ISM band)
- at least two UARTs
- some digital I/O lines
- not mandatory, but welcome:

  - enclosure for DIN rails
  - RTC with backup battery
  - EEPROM/FLASH memory

Comment: I think this kind of question would be more appropriate in hardware recommendation  stack exchange https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Did you consider using a mesh network? Both Zigbee and BlueTooth  support them.

Comment: Yep, it was an alternative I've considered but I had hard time in the past to get them working. Anyway it does not change my problem: I still need a commercial module with the other features. Do you know such a product?